# How to find all possible combinations that satisfy a condition (max and min threshold) in Python?

Tags: python

Given

```
names = ["bread","peanut_butter","yogurt","coffe"]
calories = [150,400,100,75]
```

and thresholds

```
max_calories = 500
min_calories = 250
```

I want to get all the possible food combinations , such as:

```
bread + yogurt = 250
bread + yogurt + coffe = 350
peanut_butter + yogurt = 500
peanut_butter + coffe = 475
peanut_butter = 400
```

This is what I've got so far. I managed to get only `"peanut_butter = 400"` via `def greedy` and `"bread + yogurt + coffe = 350"` via `def gready2`. But I don't know how to get all the remaining combinations via `def gready2`.

```
class Food(object):
    def __init__(self, n, c):
        self.name = n
        self.calories = c
    def getCalories(self):
        return self.calories
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}: < {self.calories} >"

def buildMenu(names, calories):
    """names, calories lists of same length.
       name a list of strings
       calories lists of numbers
       returns list of Foods"""
    menu = []
    for i in range(len(calories)):
        menu.append(Food(names[i], calories[i]))
    return menu

def greedy(items, maxCost, minCost):
    #Assumes items a list
    itemsCopy = items
    result = []
    totalCost = 0.0
    for i in range(len(itemsCopy)):
        if (itemsCopy[i].getCalories()) <= maxCost: 
            if (itemsCopy[i].getCalories()) >= minCost:
                result.append(itemsCopy[i])
                totalCost += itemsCopy[i].getCalories()         
    return (result, totalCost)

def greedy2(items, maxCost, minCost):
    #Assumes items a list
    itemsCopy = items
    result = []
    totalCost = 0.0
    for i in range(len(itemsCopy)):
        if (totalCost+itemsCopy[i].getCalories()) <= maxCost: 
            result.append(itemsCopy[i])
            totalCost += itemsCopy[i].getCalories()          
    return (result, totalCost)

def testGreedy(items, constraint, constraint2):
    taken, val = greedy(items, constraint, constraint2)
    for item in taken:
        print('   ', item)
        print("    ------------------------------------")


def testGreedy2(items, constraint, constraint2):
    taken2, val2 = greedy2(items, constraint, constraint2)
    print("   Total value of items taken =", val2 )
    for item in taken2:
        print("  ", item)



def testGreedys(foods, maxUnits, minUnits):
    print('Allocating', maxUnits,
          'calories:')
    print("")
    testGreedy(foods, maxUnits, minUnits)
    testGreedy2(foods, maxUnits, minUnits)


names = ["bread","peanut_butter","yogurt","coffe"]
calories = [150,400,100,75]
foods = buildMenu(names, calories)
testGreedys(foods, 500, 250)
```

Result of the above code

```
Allocating 500 calories:

     peanut_butter: < 400 >
        ------------------------------------
       Total value of items taken = 325.0
       bread: < 150 >
       yogurt: < 100 >
       coffe: < 75 >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The issue here**

The issue here is that you're *not* really parsing all possible combinations of your ingredients.
You're just trying to add more ingredients until you reach the maximum amount or calories allowed, but this will lead to a lot of possibilities that remain unexplored.

To generate all combinations of all lengths, I like to use the `itertools` package:

```py
from itertools import combinations, chain

names = ["bread","peanut_butter","yogurt","coffe"]

allCombinations = chain(*(combinations(names, i) for i in range(len(names) + 1)))

for combi in allCombinations:
    print(combi)
```

You can surely work out your code from here. Note that this is an exhaustive parsing of all combinations and that there can be more efficient algorithms to achieve what you want in the end.

**Full code sample**

For the sake of completeness, I've included the full Python code that you can use to find out your wanted combinations:

```py
from itertools import combinations, chain

# Inputs
names = ["bread","peanut_butter","yogurt","coffe"]
calories = [150, 400, 100, 75]
max_calories = 500
min_calories = 250

# Build mapping from name to number of calories
namesToCalories = {key:value for key, value in zip(names, calories)}

result = []

# Parse all combinations
allCombinations = chain(*(combinations(names, i) for i in range(len(names) + 1)))
for combi in allCombinations:
    # Get calories for this combination
    caloriesForThisCombination = sum((namesToCalories[name] for name in combi))
    # Test for min/max
    if caloriesForThisCombination > min_calories and caloriesForThisCombination < max_calories:
        result += [combi]

print(result)
```

Comment: i've added a code sample to demonstrate the parsing of combinations.

Comment: please edit your answer to show the updated code or ask another question on a specific error in your code!

Comment: thanks I will edit my post. I'm testing the new code you've just posted

Comment: thanks for your help @Corentin, I'm learning a lot. I've realised that the function `chain(*(combinations(names, i) for i in range(len(names))))` doesn't generate the full combination ("bread", "peanut_butter","yogurt","coffe"). Is that supposed to be so?